# how to remove rows based on some conditions

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
row  ID  YU  DV
 1    1   0   .
 2    1   .   .
 3    1   .   .
 4    1   .   .
 5    1   45  .
 6    1   .   7
 7    1   .   .
 8    1   .   .
 9    1   .   .
 10   1   65  .
 11   1   .   5
 12   1   .   .
 13   1   .   .
 14   1   .   .
 15   2   20  .
 16   2   .   .
 17   2   .   5
 18   2   .   .
 19   2   .   .
 20   2   0   .
 21   2   .   .
 22   2   .   .
 23   2   .   .
 24   2   43  .
 25   2   .   3
 26   2   .   .
 27   2   .   .
 28   2   .   .
```

So, whenever the value in YU column becomes 0, I want the row it becomes zero as well as all the rows following until the value in the YU becomes non-zero to be identified by a variable DF containing a value 1, if not zero. I want it to look this:

```
row  ID  YU  DV  DF
 1    1   0   .  1
 2    1   .   .  1
 3    1   .   .  1
 4    1   .   .  1
 5    1   45  .  0
 6    1   .   7  0
 7    1   .   .  0
 8    1   .   .  0
 9    1   .   .  0
 10   1   65  .  0
 11   1   .   5  0
 12   1   .   .  0
 13   1   .   .  0
 14   1   .   .  0
 15   2   20  .  0
 16   2   .   .  0
 17   2   .   5  0
 18   2   .   .  0
 19   2   .   .  0
 20   2   0   .  1
 21   2   .   .  1
 22   2   .   .  1
 23   2   .   .  1
 24   2   43  .  0
 25   2   .   3  0
 26   2   .   .  0
 27   2   .   .  0
 28   2   .   .  0
```

Comment: What programming language are you using and can you share any code that you have tried?

Comment: @pseudoAJ 8 I am using r. I am trying something like this : for(i in unique(data$ID)) { data$DF <- ifelse( data$YU[data$ID==i]==0,1,0)}  . However, I am not able to get the syntax to specify that the rows subsequent to YU=0 and until YU becomes > 0 only should be identified.

Comment: you really have `.` or are they `NA`? `x <- dd$YU; x[x == '.'] <- NA; +(zoo::na.locf(x) == '0')`

Comment: @rawr it is . no NA

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `data.table` and `zoo`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[, DF := na.locf(+(!as.numeric(YU)))]
df1
#    row ID YU DV DF
# 1:   1  1  0  .  1
# 2:   2  1  .  .  1
# 3:   3  1  .  .  1
# 4:   4  1  .  .  1
# 5:   5  1 45  .  0
# 6:   6  1  .  7  0
# 7:   7  1  .  .  0
# 8:   8  1  .  .  0
# 9:   9  1  .  .  0
#10:  10  1 65  .  0
#11:  11  1  .  5  0
#12:  12  1  .  .  0
#13:  13  1  .  .  0
#14:  14  1  .  .  0
#15:  15  2 20  .  0
#16:  16  2  .  .  0
#17:  17  2  .  5  0
#18:  18  2  .  .  0
#19:  19  2  .  .  0
#20:  20  2  0  .  1
#21:  21  2  .  .  1
322:  22  2  .  .  1
323:  23  2  .  .  1
#24:  24  2 43  .  0
#25:  25  2  .  3  0
#26:  26  2  .  .  0
#27:  27  2  .  .  0
#28:  28  2  .  .  0
```

Or other option is

```
with(df1, na.locf(c(NA, 0, 1)[(YU!=".") + (YU=="0")+1]))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
df %>% mutate(DF = as.integer(as.numeric(as.character(YU)) == 0)) %>% fill(DF)

   row ID YU DV DF
1    1  1  0  .  1
2    2  1  .  .  1
3    3  1  .  .  1
4    4  1  .  .  1
5    5  1 45  .  0
6    6  1  .  7  0
7    7  1  .  .  0
8    8  1  .  .  0
9    9  1  .  .  0
10  10  1 65  .  0
11  11  1  .  5  0
12  12  1  .  .  0
13  13  1  .  .  0
14  14  1  .  .  0
15  15  2 20  .  0
16  16  2  .  .  0
17  17  2  .  5  0
18  18  2  .  .  0
19  19  2  .  .  0
20  20  2  0  .  1
21  21  2  .  .  1
22  22  2  .  .  1
23  23  2  .  .  1
24  24  2 43  .  0
25  25  2  .  3  0
26  26  2  .  .  0
27  27  2  .  .  0
28  28  2  .  .  0
```